# HTML Doc not match with Get element

Tags: excel, vba

iam trying accessing HTML doc from this site 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwIE5ZwronuD81Ze5yu7DTVeaRRiNYZI6wX62WED3ix/dev

and iam using this code in my excel vba to inspect inner HTML or outer HTML

```
Dim MyBrowser As New InternetExplorer
If MyBrowser Is Nothing Then
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
End If
myUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwIE5ZwronuD81Ze5yu7DTVeaRRiNYZI6wX62WED3ix/dev"

MyBrowser.Visible = True
MyBrowser.navigate myUrl

Do

Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)

Set myhttp = MyBrowser.document
Set myObj = myhttp.DocumentElement
Debug.Print myObj.outerHTML
```

and the result is [image]

is totally different when i am doing inspect element from the browser. I can found all id for all textbox that i want to..any suggest or explanation why become like this.

many thanks for all help..

Comment: Looks like needs more time for javascript to run on page. If you wait longer before readingMyBrowser.document.body.innerHTML does the situation improve?

Comment: I will try later and inform here if this is the reason.. But iam not sure if this is the problem.. Thx